# gwt Event Handler not working any way

Tags: gwt, handler, uibinder

I have a get with this weird thing in GWT

when i set my uibinder to the getBody().addpend() the event is not firing but it works when i use RootPanel.get().add(new p1()); works. Looks like its something to do with the way you add the uibinder to the page?

working event::     `RootPanel.get().add(new p1());
not working:`

```
Document.get().getBody().appendChild(new p1().getElement());`
```

the event handler looks:

```
not working event::  Document.get().getBody().appendChild(new p1().getElement());
not working event::  Document.get().getBody().appendChild(new p1().getElement());


@UiHandler ("bleh")
void handleClick(ClickEvent e)
```

`if (lEntidad.getText().length()>1)`

```
lEntidad.setText("");
```

Comment: You might interested in [RootPanel.getBodyElement()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#getBodyElement%28%29). Read more about 
[RootPanel.get()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see all of your code to confirm this, but if you are adding widgets to your app using getElement(), then any events you add through gwt won't trickle through. There's special event logic GWT handle behind the scenes to make things work in a memory-leak safe environment.

Instead of using `Document.appendChild()`, you should be using whatever your parent widget is, or whatever the root of your ui.xml file is. For example, an `HTLMPanel`. Add your new widget directly to that, then your events on the widget should pass through.

**Summary**

Don't add elements if you have an event on the element. Add widgets instead. That solved the issue when I had it happen.